# XMLHttpRequest returns PHP and ASP as text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, asp-classic

When I run a `XMLHttpRequest` to target a PHP or ASP file, the `XMLHttpRequest`'s `.responseText` property returns the contents of the PHP or ASP file as text rather than returning the result of parsing the other file as PHP or ASP like it should (and did when I ran the same script I encountered this error in a few months ago). This is occurring for me whether I use Firefox, Chrome, or IE, and no errors are listed in the console when this occurs.

In an attempt to find out what I did wrong by starting from a known functional use of `XMLHttpRequest`, I tried using the AJAX tutorial sample code at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp. The version on their website works fine and does not have this issue, but when I create my own copy of the ***exact same code*** I keep getting the problem.

I copied the code to a new file named `ajaxTestASP.asp` and saved a copy of the target ASP code as `gethint.asp` (the same file name they use) in the same directory. Instead of `xmlhttp.responseText` being the product of parsing `gethint.asp` like it is in the tutorial page, in my copy `xmlhttp.responseText` is the unparsed full text of `gethint.asp`. To account for possible differences I have tried hosting my version on both locally and remotely, tried saving the main file as `.asp` or as `.html`, and tried creating the files in Notepad++ or in Notepad; but no matter what I do this problem persists. As far as I can tell, compared to the example on the W3Schools website I am using the same code saved as the same file types but getting different results.

What am I missing that can cause this difference?

The main test code is below (again, code gotten from the W3Schools tutorial page linked above where it works fine unlike in any version of it that I make):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function showHint(str) {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.asp?q=" + str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>
  <form action="">
    First name:
    <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
  </form>
  <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `gethint.asp` code from the same tutorial page:

```html
<%
response.expires=-1
dim a(30)
'Fill up array with names
a(1)="Anna"
a(2)="Brittany"
a(3)="Cinderella"
a(4)="Diana"
a(5)="Eva"
a(6)="Fiona"
a(7)="Gunda"
a(8)="Hege"
a(9)="Inga"
a(10)="Johanna"
a(11)="Kitty"
a(12)="Linda"
a(13)="Nina"
a(14)="Ophelia"
a(15)="Petunia"
a(16)="Amanda"
a(17)="Raquel"
a(18)="Cindy"
a(19)="Doris"
a(20)="Eve"
a(21)="Evita"
a(22)="Sunniva"
a(23)="Tove"
a(24)="Unni"
a(25)="Violet"
a(26)="Liza"
a(27)="Elizabeth"
a(28)="Ellen"
a(29)="Wenche"
a(30)="Vicky"

'get the q parameter from URL
q=ucase(request.querystring("q"))

'lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
if len(q)>0 then
  hint=""
  for i=1 to 30
    if q=ucase(mid(a(i),1,len(q))) then
      if hint="" then
        hint=a(i)
      else
        hint=hint & " , " & a(i)
      end if
    end if
  next
end if

'Output "no suggestion" if no hint were found
'or output the correct values
if hint="" then
  response.write("no suggestion")
else
  response.write(hint)
end if
%>
```

Comment: Did you set your server up correctly to process those asp/php files?

Comment: Please check your server configuration, i guess its malfunctioning

Comment: This is not what stack snippets are meant for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commenters are right. If you receive the actual source code, it means that the web server is not configured correctly to interpret the `.php`/`.asp` files and instead treat them as text files and return their contents.